# Как избежать дублирование кода в конструкторах классов в typescript?

Tags: typescript, архитектура

Один из многих классов:

```
export interface IMyClassConstructorParameters {
  name: string;
  id?: null | number;
  deleted_at?: null | string;
  created_at?: null | string;
  updated_at?: null | string;
}

export default class MyClass {
  public name: string;
  private readonly _deleted_at: null | string;
  private readonly _created_at: null | string;
  private readonly _updated_at: null | string;
  private readonly _id: null | number;

  public get id(): null | number {
    return this._id;
  }

  constructor(parameters: IMyClassConstructorParameters) {
    this._id = parameters.id
      ? parameters.id
      : null;

    this._updated_at = parameters.updated_at
      ? parameters.updated_at
      : null;

    this._created_at = parameters.created_at
      ? parameters.created_at
      : null;

    this._deleted_at = parameters.deleted_at
      ? parameters.deleted_at
      : null;

    this.name = parameters.name;
  }
}
```

**Проблема**: В конструкторе я определяю свойства `_id`, `_updated_at`, `_created_at` и `_deleted_at`. Такое определение я делаю в многих классах, т.е у меня появляется дублирование кода. ***Есть ли паттерны или общая практика решения подобных проблем?***

Конечно, можно сделать класс `Core` и вынести туда часть методов и свойств. Но мне кажется это не лучшее решение, так если мне надо будет использовать разные методы или свойства в различных классах, то мне надо будет создавать классы типа `CoreOnlyCreatedAt`, `CoreOnlyDeletedAt` и так далее.

Comment: `this._id = parameters.id || null;`

Comment: Неплохо бы узнать что в `IMyClassConstructorParameters`

Comment: @AlexeyTen С `_id` согласен) Обновил вопрос.

Comment: В принципе можно было бы сделать `Object.assign(this, parameters)` если бы совпадали имена

Comment: Так если определения полей совпадают, то зачем вообще условия? `this._id = parameters.id;` и всё. Ой, не заметил `?`

Comment: @Grundy так там ещё ж могут быть и методы общие и геттеры.

Comment: @AlexeyTen тогда там будет `undefined`. А мне нужен `null`. Но это уже не относится к этому вопросу.

Comment: Ну я так ничего лучше пачки `this._X = params.X || null` не вижу

Comment: _так там ещё ж могут быть и методы общие и геттеры_ - и в чем проблема?

Comment: а вообще, ересь эти ваши ООП-конструкторы - `g = (base, ...mix) => data =>
    Object.assign({}, ...Array.from(mix, f => f()), base, data)`

Comment: [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/MYewdgziA2CmB0w4EMBOAKAlAbgASkgBddoQBzXAXlwEcqA+fcKOeUs9GzAWACgCIxCtXQAjZBFgAaXPDkBbAJYAPTA1wATZIWQM+uA7gDyogFaxgheBIiKyYdAG8AvjLnwAgqlTIAnvAAzVBB5dCVlGQD1AKxMGXFJGS0dHl5DXGxsPgFiAAVYYmoOR1wwZHlYAC5cAHJ8whqZZDIq3AAGGWdUnNwAYW0qXGLS8taawB4QQAYQQCEQQAEQQD4QQEEQQC4QQA4QQF4QRtwKkAB3asJUAFdpXFdceu7mYgARckHhsorqmsAKEEnZ1eWt3ZAQAIOx1O50u2WufW0d2EQycI2etUAWCDzabzQD4IIBFEEWNTOMn6hBkUNS6UyfAA2vpDPVYc1WgBGAAsZziFIMeOpLWqAHZOsy0oYoezWgBmHlSFkQwgCko06q0gBsor4AF1AiBUABRZDAAAW6HYRMMJN4QA)

Answer (score 1):

не влезает в комменты.

пример ниже исключительно для примера, как вектор для размышлений.

[песочница там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBA2gfQJYBMA0NgCcCmBDKHFBAjFHAGx0ONJgFcAHFAokqAXRgF4YBBLFjwBPAHQAzLCAC2ACgDeMKmADmUABYAuGAEYADDAC+GWQEoeAPhhh6FCqYCwAKCqxYvPc4D0XmAFo0P2dQSBAqUWAqPCwzYPAIMJxRChAVWQARVlEwEAB3M0cnYIo8CAgYACFSnD4YeWcYRphkFG0bOxgAH2t6aQAjHCweHrsAbmdDYtLyqogcCrqGpvJXNgI22woumGgsJFVh9opxpybMXFZaKA2O7t39lUPNk7OmFhp2G627qD2D3iOJ0mTki00q1QAwotTk0UioALLUdQgFBmaFnM5wgDSOGEEFkGiQEEKZ2BwOcWHoYFkaO4VkUPhgAAVolAkHgKEtGvtCFhxHhgDgYPDhBCSmUWUJpOUcAAPQhgFAzap8DCzeZqyF1IxczDi8oisVguUKpUwAASlEYgwAPIb9ZK8NKML96DgLLJ1arwXMKpq5hDzPUYRiYCpqDBUGYvtsbP1BujQxjcFB6FgwDBCRBRC0XkngaTdSFoDAAI4AEh0hxwuWFov1CmaqAw2HwHzoK2oaygGDel3YRhJTWLsArACZq7X7dNGy0yJQu1de8x+wRBxNCpTqbT6TBGQAlHCl+hIXAoXU8wb8wV1o0S6JOmXynCK5Vzb3qv0+nBQxQF4f6regEmi+ZqWhQ1pYHa9bTI60oel6-oat+gaJqG4awFGpgxt0cYDEMwZJsm1BphmWY5qgeahv+jQ0Zg8SjpWk5ATOihzucbbdvOqxLgwK7trAhhDo0I5luWE4AjWLFlLOzYwJ2AnLu83brk4QnON4vh+NpOm6bpGlOFAwjWjAEJQCAQy8IoYA1rIoj2dEKgQNoeBgMIcAcNhMCucIOpFE4jIAMS4CoSDgDAAAGADy0hIFAAAqxk4BFMDqFAUCMM5PjQAKADWIAAG5XikuQRDIXh4F4ACsVUACwAOwAJwAGxVY1XgNY1tUAMzNQAHJpugwPFQiQOIFnSJm6hCkZJnmTA4glI8HJbBoQpUuQECnkQMC5bi5SlDAADkNlFVgR3OLNQoAGJLQAorKkT0OQKCJdaNrqhgb3usMihwDivn7LtuIgOI34cNo6r-biXAga+w1JTAAD81g4GdMDaADRgnIyE4AOIRmtwN4lNa7REKOSwIteAqOGKDeeUJ1o4MF2GYjfB2HkRAAHJOjgEAfdUX1JVYvC3TTD1PS932C3MwvWhYcB7cIoPgzjvjdTAACqcxTUSMC5HF6jeTsSDSIwVDMkgwC5ZmIBhoT00wHsKhpZGYC8teOAYHKUsPFN62Kvz2301dl2IzFcUy59CMK8MTLW7lsve-wnO5DzfMCzH30WBY6swLVMCSxQz0zU711UsAbLhVddswOAFC+RhMCMFIkFsvz4cmRCDGUlXFky-FoswJHCVJTa8UYBXYBV2FYB54NgWgSFc8GeIlfVxm4GQRPGBMjAcNmn0ICJK5wz8hQcwevZogQEwgxmRZAAyRLXKZ5lYB52G6jZtayIwD5pTaH3ofcorohQo1HjLSUbIOQTwsFPDec8rDaCgePSeMBp6z3ABYcwdJhpoT3F4AAAlACAfgkAqByLgXUKZSJ6jBIRJMI4+4f3-oA5y3k3JBl1ERRk8UorpCitoQALCCAD4QQAjCCAAYQQATCCAA4QQAQiCABkQGAcjADsIDIwA3CCAFYQQA4iDaMALwgcjtEwEADwg2iFFiPETI3hzCGI7HvlgF+JZeACCEGISQMhZB30go-Jxr8MB+MsKjWsfiCi2NDIyUSCAAFSnKLwKKfQABWOAq6iGmJQ6k8hjAwBvj4wYziewtw4cJIiI9kmpKgOksomSCTqCJBgPJjjCmlKIoklJaTlb4izKYCQFk7oCnULIZWwSmFlIxEgMGwzcTu2KXE1p4yMQ+FIeQzJFkcARMWY0LMSsYbDFiY+XZwgOCbNJAs2iuoyRryQeFbE+1ZClm0NknhIZ6KhHCHCWQEUunaHLPIdplTRBdIeaYQwEVCjkicOvGem9nZUlkOIbQWDN5eQKiAVAhDiyJGSKkL54KizxGxZ8iKfyADUpKoCGH8H4GAFh8WvN+L5RQ4g0RUuAAQYAxtZA4CDH5M4WKPm4pJfISl1KYA2npZCxkekZU6QMoyQg0AnmDTOHgPouwBSwFBGUb8E9hg+XpCquxkBXT9xiAcoBzJWTsgoPAl5jItkAs6fcnpfSsADM5dM3y+DgwOq2U0SZMAvWzItcSI1-qlkkLIRQqh6zw0RqaDs5WXBeChqOScgKvgtnqUzWU4EfqLm5v5YBL0B9nzw3VMnPghqi1JhaDhHo8ZLIjGOPG-NWaAJgk-GW00b4cDJwqBYX1HbQwKW7A2+4-wW35yIq2Vcb8jjbEnY8AEzx42vH4uOltS7fj+1XWMNtg1gRAA)

что есть:

- Partial
- Required
- исключение методов из параметров

чего нет:

- не извлекаются методы для подмешивания

что ещё посмотреть:

- какой-нибудь lodash + @types/lodash
- typedi

```
const [_id, created_at, deleted_at, updated_at] = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => null)
let t = 0
// -,-
console.clear()
console.log(Date.now())

class BaseA {
    _id: null | number = null;
}
class BaseB {
    deleted_at: null | string = null;
    created_at: null | string = null;
    updated_at: null | string = null;
}
class BaseC {
    logMethod() {
        logKeys(this)
    }
}

run(() => { // Partial
    interface MyClassParams extends BaseA, BaseB, BaseC { }
    class MyClass extends Helper<MyClassParams, true>(BaseA, BaseB, BaseC) {
        get id(): null | number {
            return this._id;
        }
    }
    const q$1 = new MyClass({ _id, created_at, deleted_at, updated_at })
    const q$2 = new MyClass({ _id, deleted_at, updated_at })
})
run(() => { // Required
    interface MyClassParams extends BaseA, BaseB, BaseC { }
    class MyClass extends Helper<MyClassParams>(BaseA, BaseB, BaseC) {
        get id(): null | number {
            return this._id;
        }
    }
    const q$1 = new MyClass({ _id, created_at, deleted_at, updated_at })
    const q$2 = new MyClass({ _id, deleted_at, updated_at })
})

// --------------

type Ctor = { new(...args: any[]): any }

// #region `OmitType` https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479659/4794368
// 1 Transform the type to flag all the undesired keys as 'never'
type FlagExcludedType<Base, Type> = { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Type ? never : Key };
// 2 Get the keys that are not flagged as 'never'
type AllowedNames<Base, Type> = FlagExcludedType<Base, Type>[keyof Base];
// 3 Use this with a simple Pick to get the right interface, excluding the undesired type
type OmitType<Base, Type> = Pick<Base, AllowedNames<Base, Type>>;
// 4 Exclude the Function type to only get properties
type ConstructorType<T> = OmitType<T, Function>;
// #endregion

function Helper<T, P extends boolean = false>(...superCtorList: Ctor[]):
    new (params: P extends true ? OmitType<Partial<T>, Function> : OmitType<T, Function>) => T {
    //@ts-ignore
    return class {
        constructor(params: any) {
            // TODO: добавить извлечение методов
            const superList = Array.from(superCtorList, Ctor => new Ctor())
            // const _params = Object.assign({}, ...superList, params)
            Object.assign(this, ...superList)
            Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
                if (key in params)
                    //@ts-ignore
                    this[key] = params[key]
            })
        }
    }
}

function logKeys(q: {}) {
    console.log(`keys: ${Object.keys(q)}`)
}

function run(f: Function): void {
    console.log(``)
    console.log(`${++t} -- >`)
    try { f() } catch (e) { }
    console.log(`${t} -- <`)
}

// --------------

// test: {
//     abstract class Base<T = any> {
//         constructor(params: Partial<T>) {
//             Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
//                 if (key in params)
//                     //@ts-ignore
//                     this[key] = params[key]
//             })
//         }
//     }
//     class BaseA extends Base<BaseA> {
//         _id: null | number = null;
//     }
//     class BaseB extends Base<BaseB>{
//         deleted_at: null | string = null;
//         created_at: null | string = null;
//         updated_at: null | string = null;
//     }
// }
```

Comment: Песочница битая - показывает только это: `const [_id, created_at, deleted_at, updated_at] = Array.from({ length: 10 : co, d_iattanyd,dgupngy.y.au]Ard,au -,A1rr`

Comment: спс, поправил ..

Comment: Ответ оказался сильным для меня. С `Partial` разобрался. Но вот с остальным не понятки. Что вы имели в виду под: `Required`, `исключение методов из параметров`, `не извлекаются методы для подмешивания` - пожалуйста, подкиньте ссылок на почитать. Так же не понял зачем смотреть `lodash + @types/lodash`, `typedi`?

Comment: начнём  с этого [песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwChkTkAHDbAQQC5k4QBPY0izLAIToedPMqwBhbkxYksEMAAsA9gBMAIgAoAlHQBuM4HMIBfQoUg4wdfMgQyQx-uxx10UMMDgAbADwPsOAHzIAvAS6yPpGJgTmltZsXnQAShAAjgCuwFAQch4CPv6BwYYQxqYRVmA2McgKmba+AfhB+oQA9I3IAMRpAObAlsgABgDyWMBgACqMZBC9yFJgYGR2zcaIANYy6tAwLjIA7gB0FliNcI0ArCcALADsAJwAbCfXjVfX5wDMtwAchuMocG4ccBwEAANMgxhMauEANoAaQgjGQoGQy3hMhgyABQIAunRMRBYfCscgIAAPSAgOR4cEoAD8yBAEHWUGQdDhCN0AG5vhNkAAjf6AkFgn6Qv540HU7xQlGMNEYwVYrlgH7mAVAiUinKoYAIZZqoX88XCiHeJUqyojSEINwjUEAMSSIAQTkspqaLVaEApnW6ICAA)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mixins - как жеж мы раньше жили без `class` в JS ("lodash + @types/lodash". Имелось ввиду посмотреть как реализован тип(@types/lodash) функции `mixin` в какой-нибудь библиотеке)

Comment: typedi - DI для TS [статья, третья ссылка из гугла](https://3-info.ru/post/22879). Используется например в typeorm который используется в nestjs.

Comment: "typedi ... Используется например в typeorm ..." - вроде, по крайней мере упоминается на их страничке в Гитхаб.